# ajax post getting value in CLASSIC asp

Tags: ajax, jquery, post, asp-classic

I am trying to get the value of the posted textbox using jquery AJAX:

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submitButton').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.asp",
            data:  $("#form1").serialize(),
            cache: false,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(responseText){
                alert(responseText);
            },
            error: function(resposeText){
                alert(resposeText);
            },
        });

    return false;
});
 });
```

And this is the **test.asp** page:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%
dim vwPW

  vwPW = request.QueryString("vwPW")

  response.write "returned " & vwPW
%>
```

And my form is:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
          <table width="100" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td><input name="vwPW" id="vwPW" type="password" class="textBox" maxlength="10"  /></td>
                <td><button class="GreyB" id="submitButton" name="submitButton"><span style="color:#000">Log in</span></button></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
</form>
```

All i get is "retuned" and nothing after that. What would i be doing incorrect?

David

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your ajax is using `POST`, ASP will need to get the value using `request.form` instead of `request.querystring` - alternatively, change your ajax to `GET`.

Comment: Thanks i knew it was something little.

Answer (score 2):

Your form is POSTing so you can't access the variables you send via `Request.QueryString` but rather via `Request.Form`. Alternatively, change your ajax call to `type:'get'`.