# How to get a button to work without doing a pagepostback

Tags: c#

I have a page that I have an audio and video setup on but when I submit the data it reloads the page.  How can I get the data to insert without reloading the page?  I have tried the following and it doesn't work.  The submit button does not work with this function.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSumbit" runat="server"  Text="Add Player Stats" BackColor="Black" BorderColor="Yellow" BorderStyle="Groove" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Vani" ForeColor="Yellow" OnClientClick="yourfunction();return false;" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

Comment: Use javascript for doing client-side only, are you using Asp or MVC? Javascript in combination with JQuery, even better.

Comment: Try putting all your controls in UpdatePanel. It won't refresh the page.

Comment: AJAX would work.  Either using an UpdatePanel or using jQuery.

Comment: My vote would be jQuery or PageMethods.

Comment: If you are using ASP then you should go for AJAX or UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery loaded Try adding `event.preventDefault();` to the beginning of your javascript function that gets called on OnClientClick. Then pass the data using an ajax call from the client end.

```
yourfunction(){
 event.preventDefault();
 // then add your code for submission here
 //something like 
 $.ajax({
       url: "submission.aspx/submitData",
       type: "POST",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       data: data
  })
  .done(function (data) { //success function})
  .fail(function (jqXHR, status) { //error function });
}
```

and have something like this on your server side

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static void SubmitData(string[] data) {
    //save data;
 }
```

For more info on how to do this, [take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530409/ajax-post-getting-value-in-classic-asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax:
First change your control to be plain html, and use CSS (trust me this will change your life. It is easy to deal with pure HTML/CSS then relying on those custom controls from .Net):

1. `<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" />`
2. Attache JavaScript event handler with AJAX request:

   $("btnSubmit").click(function(){
          $.post( "yourpage.aspx", function( ) {
              alert("success");
         });
       });

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"` this invokes the postback.