# How to pass a form field value in a href that would be taken by another ASP page

Tags: asp-classic, href

I've a form that points to itself on POST operation to process data. This part is good. Now in the form I've a textbox and a button (X) that is used for another purpose as well. When this button X is clicked it should take the input value from the text box and point to another ASP page, process data and return the value...and this is the part I'm unable to figure out... Let me explain this in a bit more clearly..

form name=frmAccounts method=Post action="self.asp" 
... 
... 
name ---> Textbox 
function  ---> textbox  ::   search button(X) <--> sales.asp 
Description  --->textbox 
... 
... 
Form Submit ---> button
Form ends

Now..suppose I enter function as "Sales" in the textbox, then when I click on the search button it would look at another ASP page like sales.asp that will query for relevant description and populate the description box...Then the form submit will call the self.asp to do its function.

Question: How can I pass value from function textbox, via search button, to sales.asp for processing and return back the value.

Things I've tried so far with no luck
1) Functions using #include method 
2) Button onClick method by passing Request.Form data
3) href option by passing the URL by adding the form data - URL does not take the value
some other methods after Googling through many forums but with no joy.

Any help please?

Comment: You can do this using something like jquery to do a AJAX call that will post the data to the `sales.asp` and return a response that you can then interpret.

Comment: I'd recommend you look at something like this [ajax post getting value in CLASSIC asp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530409/ajax-post-getting-value-in-classic-asp).

Comment: @AllBlond What's not clear they have a form in [tag:asp-classic] and want to trigger a search on a button that returns a response and populates a value (perhaps in the form). Not sure how the "hek" (*heck*) that's not clear?

Comment: Thanks Lankymart..I'm a total illiterate to AJAX.. Is this something I can write within ASP file or call in #Include?

Comment: AJAX is Asynchronous [tag:JavaScript] so it's client side not server-side code like [tag:asp-classic]. Anything that affects the client (browser) uses client side code like [tag:JavaScript]. All ASP code is processed by the IIS server before it is sent to the client and cannot affect client state.

Comment: You write your javascript into your HTML (that maybe a ASP page but the javascript goes inside the `<head>` or as the last element in the `<body>` of your HTML page. The javascript will trigger an AJAX post to an ASP page (`sales.asp`) in that page you do your logic to return your value using `Response.Write()` and whatever content type you want to return. The AJAX will return this response and manipulate the form client-side as you see fit based on the value returned.

Comment: Thanks a ton Lankymart.. I think you've explained enough for me to move further. I think I'm now clear on what needs to be done and will give it a shot..Thanks again for you time and suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

Like Lankymart says, do something like this:

Self.asp

```
<form action="self.asp" name="myform" id="myform">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<br /><input type="text" name="functionbox" id="functionbox" />
<br /><input type="button" name="search" value="search" id="search" />
<br /><input type="text" name="Description" id="Description" />
<br /><input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#search").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            data: {'functionbox': $("#functionbox").val()},
            url: '/sales.asp',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    $("#Description").val(data);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

sales.asp

```
<%@ LANGUAGE = JScript %>
var functionbox =  Request.Form("functionbox").Item;
var answer = getAnswer(functionbox); // your code here
%><%= answer %>
```

Comment: Thank you Sotiris and apologies for the late response. Totally lost track of this thread as I found solution to my issue.